# Google Cloud Storage Signed URL V4 too slow

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

im using php google SDK (PHP 7.2.27), The process to create signed url v4 takes >1500 ms. what i want to ask is it this normal? or something wrong with my setup? can it be optimized? the real code have caching mechanism so its solved the problem when the url already created, it will be problem if happen for the first time. here's the part of code to create signed url v4 :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$bucketName = <REDACTED>
$objectName = <REDACTED>

$process_time = microtime(true);
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->object($objectName);
$url = $object->signedUrl(
    # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
    new \DateTime('30 sec'),
    [
        'version' => 'v4',
        'keyFilePath' => dirname(__FILE__)."/<REDACTED>.json"
    ]
);
$process_time = microtime(true) - $process_time;
echo "Process Time : ".$process_time."\n";

print('Generated GET signed URL:' . PHP_EOL);
print($url . PHP_EOL);
```

Update:

- the cause is at "$storage = new StorageClient();"
- using php 8.1 and its still takes >1500ms
- this is snoop file of that "new StorageClient()" do :
  [image]

Comment: I cannot answer for PHP 7.2 and libraries as that version is at its end of life two years ago. 1,500 ms is a very long time. Profile your code to see what is taking so long. Generating a signature is not so complex as to require more than a few milliseconds. To save some time, test with PHP 7.4 or 8.1 to give yourself a comparison.

Comment: its still takes 1500 on php 8.1 , its slow at "$storage = new StorageClient();". im updating my post

Comment: Your **snoop** file indicates that your code is spending 1,000 ms trying to communicate with the metadata service. Where is your code running? How have you set up authorization (service account, gcloud credentials, etc)? You have an authorization time issue and not a signing issue.

Comment: its only beginning but "new StorageClient()" takes 1500ms.  didnt know what i have to do with authorization, the code running in my internal server (no firewall or complex network, as comparison same server onnected flawlessly to AWS with no delay) . still confused

Comment: Review the documentation on how to authorize your code. Your code is using credentials of some form. If you are running this code on your internal server, then the code should **not** be trying to connect to the metadata server.

Comment: Seeing something similar in Go. SignedURL taking about 40ms. Not sustainable when you need to sign a bunch of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
```

to

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
     'projectId' => '<your_related_project_id_to_object_bucket_location>'
]);
```

the first one (without parameter) is an example from official [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) that slows down the connection about 1500ms, as someone totally new in GCP this documentation bring more confusion than clear explanation, dont use it.